# Should I avoid inheriting from std::iostream?

Tags: c++, inheritance, iostream

I'm writing a class that will read/write specifically formatted text files. I considered inheriting from `std::iostream`, but in searching with Google, I found some comments/suggestions that I should not inherit from `std::iostream`.

Are there reasons I should avoid inheriting directly from `std::iostream`? Should I inherit from something more low-level like `std::basic_iostream` instead?

Comment: In general I think rather than inheriting you should simply have an `std::iostream` as a member.

Comment: @JonathanMee You may be right; it's the old `has-a` vs `is-a` argument. Since my class will be directly reading/writing files I figured it fell more on the `has-a` side so I wanted to try inheriting.

Comment: To provide a formatter of whatever kind, I'd prefer a class **using** `std::ostream` and `std::istream` references.

Comment: _'so I wanted to try inheriting'_ That will definitely make the correct implementation harder.

Comment: Technically the main problem with inheriting is that the destructor is not virtual. In the case of `std::basic_iostream` the destructor is virtual, therefore it might be possible to inherit from it without troubles. The fact is that what you *should* do, instead, is just applying composition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The iostream takes data in various formats, and converts it to a stream of bytes that's sent to the stream buffer. It does *most* of this by calling formatting functions in an associated locale (e.g., deciding whether a number should be represented as `1.234,56` or `1,234.56` or `1234.56` is up to the locale).

Once the data is formatted according to the locale, it's then written to a stream buffer. The stream buffer is what converts the formatted data into the format suitable to the external file (e.g., dealing with UTF-8 vs. UTF-16 vs. ISO-8859).

As such, there's almost no chance you want to change the iostream to change the formatting. If you want to change how individual items are formatted, you'd do that by changing the locale. If you want to change how that result is converted to an external file format, you'd change the file buffer.